# Can UI Text inspector be extended in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

```cs
[CanEditMultipleObjects()]
[CustomEditor(typeof(UnityEngine.UI.Text), true)]
public class CameraExtension : UnityEditor.UI.TextEditor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();
        if (GUILayout.Button("New Button!"))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I want to extend UI Text inspector in Unity3D. I tried it on the Camera component and it works fine, but it doesn't work on UI Text.

Comment: Try creating a class for the custom Text you want, then create another class for the editor extension. See accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052183/extending-unity-ui-components-with-custom-inspector

Comment: I know I can do it like this, but I need to add this script on each gameobject which I need to use. I want to modify the original component, then every exist component has my function.

Answer (score 3):

No, currently it's not possible to extend `UnityEngine.UI.Text` inspector (or any other inspector for components from `UnityEngine.UI` namespace).

The problem is due to assemblies getting loaded in this order:

1. UnityEngine/UnityEditor
2. User Assemblies
3. Modules (`UnityEngine.UI` is here)

Assemblies that get loaded later take over custom editors defined in previous assemblies, that's why you won't see your custom editor working.