# Extending UnityEngine.UI.Image and add extra field available in Inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui, unity3d-editor

I am trying to extend `UnityEngine.UI.Image` like that

```
public class MyImage : Image {
   public string Comment;
}
```

But I do not see extra text field `Comment` in inspector. Is it possible to add extra field that would be available in inspector?

**PS** It triggered as duplicated for [Extending Unity UI components with custom Inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052183/extending-unity-ui-components-with-custom-inspector) but it is not dupe. I do not ask anything about `custom Inspector`. It is just regular field with `default Inspector`. The problem is that field is not appearing in inspector at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending Unity UI components with custom Inspector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052183/extending-unity-ui-components-with-custom-inspector)

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the Inspector GUI cannot inherit from base class automatically. You need to write that yourself, just like what is described in [Extending Unity UI components with custom Inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052183/extending-unity-ui-components-with-custom-inspector).

MyImage.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class MyImage : Image
{
    public string Comment;
}
```

MyImageEditor.cs

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(MyImage))]
public class MyImageEditor : UnityEditor.UI.ImageEditor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();//Draw inspector UI of ImageEditor

        MyImage image = (MyImage)target;
        image.Comment = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Comment", image.Comment);
    }
}
```

Result:
[image: MyImage's Inspector GUI]