# Variables not showing on inspector when I extend Unity UI button

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

Variables not showing on inspector when I extend Unity UI button.
I wanted to add some extra functionality to unity button, and to do this i just extaned this button and wanted to have 2 fields.
But noticed that those fields are not available in unity inspector, unless i change to debug
Code:

```
public class PlayPauseButton : Button
{
    [SerializeField] private Image playGraphic;
    [SerializeField] private Image pauseGraphic;
    
    private bool _isPlaying;
}
```

I was expecting to see the variables on inspector, on normal mode. I can view them on debug but it can be a bit tricky

Answer (score 1):

For examle I take my project ui extensions.
I needed to add a variable to contentSizeFitter.

This code I'll use for ContentSizeFitter

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(LayoutGroup))]
public class Zdy_ContentSizeFitter : ContentSizeFitter
{
    private LayoutGroup layoutGroup;

    [SerializeField] private ContentSize_Element contentSizeElement;

    protected override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
        layoutGroup = GetComponent<LayoutGroup>();
    }

    ...
   
}
```

We will add this variable in inspector

```
private ContentSize_Element contentSizeElement;
```

1. Create folder named "Editor anywhere like this:

[image]

2. Create Extension Editor Script in this folder like this:

[image]

3. Сreate a script that includes these methods:

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
protected override void OnEnable()
protected virtual void DrawConfigInfo()
```

4. Do like me) :

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Zdy_ContentSizeFitter))]
public class Zdy_ContentSizeFitterEditor : ContentSizeFitterEditor
{

        private SerializedProperty contentSizeElement;

        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            this.serializedObject.Update();

            this.DrawConfigInfo();
            this.serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();

            base.OnInspectorGUI();

        }

        protected override void OnEnable()
        {
            base.OnEnable();
            this.contentSizeElement = this.serializedObject.FindProperty("contentSizeElement");

        }

        protected virtual void DrawConfigInfo()
        {
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(this.contentSizeElement);

        }
    }
```

And now we can see this variable in inspector:
[image]

"ContentSizeFitterEditor" we take from UnityEditor.UI;

In your case we should inherit from "ButtonEditor"
Like this:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.UI;

public class Zdy_ContentSizeFitterEditor : ButtonEditor
```

For an in-depth study of this issue, it is better to follow the link in the previous answer))

And you can check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052183/extending-unity-ui-components-with-custom-inspector) here is an example with a button

Comment: If we put the script on editor folder, it will not be available outside the editor runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make folder named 'Editor' on Assets
and PlayPauseButton Script into Editor folder! :D

I got hint in
https://niclasgleesborg.home.blog/2019/05/23/extend-ui-button-behaviour-in-unity-and-create-a-custom-inspector/

Comment: If you were to put the `PlayPauseButton` script in an Editor folder it wouldn't be available outside the editor at runtime. The custom inspector script does need to be in an Editor folder.